# Python copy directory and change xls to xlsx

Tags: python

I now have several folders and excel files under c:/Users/Manda/Test:

c:/Users/Manda/Test/BankStatement/Bank1/Year2019/Jan-Jun2019.xls

c:/Users/Manda/Test/BankStatement/Bank1/Year2019/Jul-Dec2019.xls

c:/Users/Manda/Test/BankStatement/Bank1/Year2020/Jan-Dec2020.xls

c:/Users/Manda/Test/BankStatement/Bank2/Year2020/Jan-Jun2020.xls

There are two things I need to accomplish:

First, I need to make a new folder under c:/Users/Manda/Test with a suffix and copy all the existing directories into this new folder.

Second, I need to convert all the xls files to xlsx.

In a word, the new folders and excel files should be:

c:/Users/Manda/Test/BankStatement_copy/Bank1/Year2019/Jan-Jun2019.xlsx

c:/Users/Manda/Test/BankStatement_copy/Bank1/Year2019/Jul-Dec2019.xlsx

c:/Users/Manda/Test/BankStatement_copy/Bank1/Year2020/Jan-Dec2020.xlsx

c:/Users/Manda/Test/BankStatement_copy/Bank2/Year2020/Jan-Jun2020.xlsx

I have written the code for converting xls to xlsx as following (but it adds a new folder):

```
def xls2xlsx():

    path='xlsx_folder'
    isExists=os.path.exists('xlsx_folder')

    if not isExists:

        os.makedirs(path) 
 
        print (path+' Successfully Built')

    else:

        print (path+' Existed dir')


    file_list = os.listdir()
    parent_list = os.getcwd()
    print('file_list',file_list)

    for file in file_list:

        if (file.split(".")[-1]=='xls') or (file.split(".")[-1]=='XLS'):

            content=xlrd.open_workbook(filename=file,encoding_override='gbk')

            df = pd.read_excel(content,header=0)

            print(df)

            df.to_excel('xlsx_folder\\'+file.split(".")[0]+'.xlsx',encoding='utf_8_sig')


    print('Finished.')
```

I am confused about how to make copies of folders in the directory and how to combine it with the xls to xlsx codes. I am thinking about using os.walk or shutil but I am not sure.

Thanks in advance.